# Perform javascript on html content from js file

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

This is a big headache.

I have a simple js file consisting of nothing but document.write() blocks of html content, that I need to perform jquery on.

To put things in perspective, the js file, included like this:

```
<script language="JavaScript" src="http://external-java-file.js"/>
```

dumps news in a batch of div's. the trouble is, I need to perform javascript on each seperate article-div (to include it into a custom javascript "scroller". is there anyway for me to firstly "hide" the entire block of news, and then per-div add it it my scroller.
Basically I have this from the js file:

```
<div class="newsContainer">
<div class="newsArticle">bla bla bla</div>
<div class="newsArticle">bla bla bla</div>
<div class="newsArticle">bla bla bla</div>
</div>
```

Since it's all coming from this stinking external js file through document.write, I can't access it with a seperate code block like this:

```
<script>
$(document).onload(function(){
$("div.newsContainer").css("display","none");
});
</script>
```

I'm pretty sure I'm at the end of the road, but I'd like to see if any smart minds have genious solution

Comment: you cant't edit the external js file?

Comment: @MeLight, sadly no -.- I wish to god I could.

Comment: is there any change if we use `$(document).ready()` instead of onload

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

### HTML

```
<div id="news">
    <script language="JavaScript" src="http://external-java-file.js"/>
</div>
```

### JavaScript

```
$(function() {
    $('#news .newsArticle').hide();
});
```

If the script is using document.write(), then you will be able to access it's container, #news, once the page has loaded and edit it that way.

Answer (score 2):

You want to use

```
$(document).ready(function() {
// .. put code here.
});
```

This will make sure the page and other JS has loaded first.

Firebug console in Firefox is your friend, as you will be able to test your jQuery on the page.

Comment: You can also use `$(function() { //..code });` which is the jQuery shorthand equivalent.

Comment: I prefer to use the above, makes it clearer to the next person to support it that it will only be executed when the DOM has loaded. Comes down to preference I guess. :)

Comment: that's fair enough, just thought I'd include it for lazy people (like me) :)

Answer (score 0):

Make a css style to hide the newsContainer initially:

```
.newsContainer {
  display: none;
}
```

Then add your other stuff in the document ready function of jQuery:

```
$(function() {
  // do your stuff here
});
```

If you don't know when that external script does it's job with the news divs, make use of JavaScript's `setTimeout`. Also remember to set .newsContainer to visible after you're done.